Using data from the Fine Guidance System (HST)
Has anyone been able to successfully use data from the Hubble Space Telescope's fine guidance system in order to create light curves?
I found a bunch of older papers that reference this instrument, but no one goes through the methods section with enough detail for that resource to be useful.
The FGS documentation is old, talks about a bunch of IRAF software that seem to be really hard to download. I am looking for a relatively straightforward, preferably pythonic solution to use FGS data.
Thanks!

Which papers did you find and did not consider helpful or useful? I find quite a few, too, so what you referenced will be helpful. What information are you missing, where exactly do you get stuck? Please be specific. What is wrong with the IRAF software? It's readily available and well-documented, its latest release from April this year. The more you elaborate, the more helpful any answer can be.

Here are the papers I referenced:
A Hubble Space Telescope transit light curve for GJ 436b
DOI: 10.1051/0004-6361:200810013
HST/FGS Photometry of Planetary Transits of HD 209458
DOI: 10.1063/1.1774516
Perhaps, this is my own lack of knowledge, but I seem to have trouble in how to use IRAF for the data reduction/light curve fitting pipeline. I have RAW fits files from the FGS.
Questions I have:

How can I find my star in the image based on RA and Dec? (I have some knowledge on how to do this using python via Astropy's WCS)
How can I calcuate photometry values for a light curve?

